# How to show markings on QDial in PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qdial

I am designing a ui in `qt-desginer` where I have added `dial`. It looks like below:

[image]

It doesn't have any markings. Is it possible to add some markings to understand it better. Something like below:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, QDial is a widget that has never been really cared about, mostly because it's scarcely used, but also because many feature needs might change its behavior in inconsistent ways. In any case, this is not possible from Designer.

It can be *partially* done by subclassing QDial and promoting it in designer, but you'll end up having numbers drawn *over* the notches or the dial itself, which will look ugly.

In order to achieve what you want, you need to use a custom widget that *contains* the dial, and eventually promote *that* widget, but you'll not be able to see it in designer nor set its properties (unless you create a Designer plugin, which is not very easy). This is achieved by setting the container layout margins, so that there's always enough space to show the values as text.

This is a possible implementation. Consider that, for obvious reasons, if you have a big value range with a small dial, the numbers will overlap.

```
class ValueDial(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    _dialProperties = ('minimum', 'maximum', 'value', 'singleStep', 'pageStep',
        'notchesVisible', 'tracking', 'wrapping', 
        'invertedAppearance', 'invertedControls', 'orientation')
    _inPadding = 3
    _outPadding = 2
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # remove properties used as keyword arguments for the dial
        dialArgs = {k:v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in self._dialProperties}
        for k in dialArgs.keys():
            kwargs.pop(k)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.dial = QtWidgets.QDial(self, **dialArgs)
        layout.addWidget(self.dial)
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)
        # make the dial the focus proxy (so that it captures focus *and* key events)
        self.setFocusProxy(self.dial)

        # simple "monkey patching" to access dial functions
        self.value = self.dial.value
        self.setValue = self.dial.setValue
        self.minimum = self.dial.minimum
        self.maximum = self.dial.maximum
        self.wrapping = self.dial.wrapping
        self.notchesVisible = self.dial.notchesVisible
        self.setNotchesVisible = self.dial.setNotchesVisible
        self.setNotchTarget = self.dial.setNotchTarget
        self.notchSize = self.dial.notchSize
        self.invertedAppearance = self.dial.invertedAppearance
        self.setInvertedAppearance = self.dial.setInvertedAppearance

        self.updateSize()

    def inPadding(self):
        return self._inPadding

    def setInPadding(self, padding):
        self._inPadding = max(0, padding)
        self.updateSize()

    def outPadding(self):
        return self._outPadding

    def setOutPadding(self, padding):
        self._outPadding = max(0, padding)
        self.updateSize()

    # the following functions are required to correctly update the layout
    def setMinimum(self, minimum):
        self.dial.setMinimum(minimum)
        self.updateSize()

    def setMaximum(self, maximum):
        self.dial.setMaximum(maximum)
        self.updateSize()

    def setWrapping(self, wrapping):
        self.dial.setWrapping(wrapping)
        self.updateSize()

    def updateSize(self):
        # a function that sets the margins to ensure that the value strings always
        # have enough space
        fm = self.fontMetrics()
        minWidth = max(fm.width(str(v)) for v in range(self.minimum(), self.maximum() + 1))
        self.offset = max(minWidth, fm.height()) / 2
        margin = self.offset + self._inPadding + self._outPadding
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)

    def translateMouseEvent(self, event):
        # a helper function to translate mouse events to the dial
        return QtGui.QMouseEvent(event.type(), 
            self.dial.mapFrom(self, event.pos()), 
            event.button(), event.buttons(), event.modifiers())

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FontChange:
            self.updateSize()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.dial.mousePressEvent(self.translateMouseEvent(event))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.dial.mouseMoveEvent(self.translateMouseEvent(event))

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.dial.mouseReleaseEvent(self.translateMouseEvent(event))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        radius = min(self.width(), self.height()) / 2
        radius -= (self.offset / 2 + self._outPadding)
        invert = -1 if self.invertedAppearance() else 1
        if self.wrapping():
            angleRange = 360
            startAngle = 270
            rangeOffset = 0
        else:
            angleRange = 300
            startAngle = 240 if invert > 0 else 300
            rangeOffset = 1
        fm = self.fontMetrics()

        # a reference line used for the target of the text rectangle
        reference = QtCore.QLineF.fromPolar(radius, 0).translated(self.rect().center())
        fullRange = self.maximum() - self.minimum()
        textRect = QtCore.QRect()

        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
        for p in range(0, fullRange + rangeOffset, self.notchSize()):
            value = self.minimum() + p
            if invert < 0:
                value -= 1
                if value < self.minimum():
                    continue
            angle = p / fullRange * angleRange * invert
            reference.setAngle(startAngle - angle)
            textRect.setSize(fm.size(QtCore.Qt.TextSingleLine, str(value)))
            textRect.moveCenter(reference.p2().toPoint())
            qp.drawText(textRect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, str(value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dial = ValueDial(minimum=1, maximum=11)
    dial.setNotchesVisible(True)
    dial.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: screenshot of the dial]